# Dimension of the Zariski closure of certain subset of matrices

Tags: algebraic-geometry, classical-algebraic-geometry

Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field, and $V\subseteq K^n$ a vector subspace of dimension $k$. For a basis of $V$, suppose the map from $V$ to $K^k$ which takes elements of $V$ to their coordinates is onto. Now let $S_V\subseteq M_{n\times k} $ be the set of matrices $A\in M_{n\times k}$  such that the image $Im(A)=A(K^k)=V$.

I need to show that $\dim \overline{S_V}=k^2$ (Here by $\overline{S_V}$ I mean the closure in the Zariski topology in the variety $M_{n\times k}$).

The exercise recommends as a hint using the map $\phi:S_v\to M_{k\times k}$ which takes matrices of $S_V$ to their top $k\times k$ blocks.

I know the dimension of $M_{k\times k}$ is $k^2$, which surely must help to prove the equality.

Also, I think is clear that $\phi$ the restriction to $S_V$ of the same map from $M_{n\times k}$ to $M_{k\times k}$, which is a morphism of irreducible varieties which is onto and also dominant. However, I'm stuck at this point, since I don't exactly know how to use the definition of $S_V$ or the fact that the coordinate map $V\to K^k$ is onto to move on.

Any hint about how to get in the right direction would be very helpful.

Comment: Have you tried an example in coordinates (preferably with reasonably small $n,k$)?

Comment: Zariski. Not Zarinski

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**New answer (there was a confusion on the problem statement; see below):** $S_V$ consists of matrices $A\in M_{n\times k}$ (i.e., linear transformations $K^k\to K^n$) such that $A(K^k)=V$. In particular, it is a subset of the Zariski closed subset $T_V\subset M_{n\times k}$ consisting of linear transformations $A\colon K^k\to K^n$ such that $A(K^k)\subset V$, and we may instead take the closure of $S_V$ inside $T_V$.

But $T_V$ can simply be identified with the set of linear transformations $A\colon K^k\to V$, i.e., $M_{k\times k}$, upon choosing a basis for $V$. Now, $S_V\subset M_{k\times k}$ consists of linear transformations $A\colon K^k\to K^k$ which are surjective, i.e., such that $\det(A)\ne0$. But this is a Zariski open subset of $T_V$, hence $\overline S_V=T_V$. We already know that $\dim(T_V)=k^2$, since $T_V\simeq\mathbb A^{k^2}$ as an algebraic variety.

---

**Old answer:** Assume without loss that $V=K e_1\oplus \cdots\oplus Ke_k\subset K^n=Ke_1\oplus\cdots\oplus Ke_n$. Then your variety $S_V$ consists of matrices $A\in M_{n\times k}$ such that $Ae_1,\dots,Ae_k$ spans $K^k$, i.e., $\det(Ae_1,\dots,Ae_k)\ne0$. Thus $S_V$ is a Zariski open subset of $M_{n\times k}$, i.e., the closure is $M_{n\times k}$, of dimension $nk$.

Comment: This is not a complete list of the relevant conditions (remember, the image has to equal $V$, not just contain it) and arrives at an incorrect conclusion as a result. (To see this, try $n=2, k=1$ in the above.) (Edit: I'm not the downvoter.)

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I didn't understand the question. I thought $S_V$ is the set of linear transformations $A\colon K^n\to K^k$ such that $A|_V$ is surjective, in which case I believe the answer is correct. (is $A$ a linear transformation $K^k\to K^n$? I'm quite confused by the notation.)

Comment: From the last sentence of the first paragraph: "... let $S_V$ be the set of matrices $A\in M_{n\times k}$ such that $im(A)=V$." I agree that the question could be a little clearer, but I think that sentence is okay.

Comment: So is $A$ a linear transformation $K^k\to K^n$? If so, I will edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: Also, (correct me if I’m wrong) I believe the argument here is can sort of help, in the sense that $S_V$ would correspond in $M_{k\times k}$ to the open set here  described, after projecting through $\phi$. Therefore, its closure would be $M_{k\times k}$ which has the dimension the exercise asks for.

Comment: @AndresMolina You wrote $A(K^n)=V$, which means $A$ must be a linear transformation $K^n\to V$. But if that's what you mean, then I believe my answer is correct. Do you mean $A$ is a linear map $K^k\to K^n$, and that $A(K^k)=V$? It would be helpful to me if you re-wrote the question, I don't understand it.

Comment: @AndresMolina If $A\colon K^n\to K^k$, then what does it mean to require $A(K^n)=V$? By definition, $V$ is a subspace of $K^n$, not $K^k$.

Comment: You are correct, sorry. I got confused with the dimensions. The linear map $A$ is of the form $A:K^k \to K^n$.